# how to show a section based on radio button selected

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I am generating some radio buttons using ng-repeat, here is the code

```
<input type="radio" ng-repeat="i in items" name="myRadio{{$index}}" value="{{i.val}}" />
```

its generating 2 radio buttons, I want to show a section only if the radio button of value "sftp" is selected, how can I do that?

```
<div ng-show="????">
    this section is visible when radio button having value sftp is selected
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a model to both radios:

```
<input ng-model="myRadio" type="radio" ng-repeat="i in items" name="myRadio{{$index}}" value="{{i.val}}" />
```

And just do:

```
ng-show="myRadio == 'sftp'"
```